Resharper C++ doesn't replace the existing parenthesis after entering function parameters
I'm using ReSharper 2024.1.2 on a C++ VS2022 project. I have an issue with something very basic, but I couldn't find a solution.
When I type auto-complete a method name, the cursor gets between the opening and closing parameters. Once I type my parameters, I type the closing bracket but it adds a new one instead of replacing the existing one. The gif below should be self explanatory.
I don't have the issue with Intellisense if I disable resharper.
Any idea?


I finally found out the solution thanks to ReSharper support:
This option needs to be ON:
ReSharper | Options | Environment | Editor | Behavior | Delimiter characters | Auto-insert pair brackets, parentheses and quotes

